# How to produce this figure of thin-plate splines fit to observed data with contours plotted?

Tags: r, plot, statistics

How does one reproduce this figure from Elements of Statistical Learning page 166?

I understand that a regression is fit to the data using `age` and `obesity` as features. But I am wondering how to represent the fitted surface using contours as is shown in the figure. I would prefer an R implementation because I believe that is what was used in this case.

[image: contour plot]

Comment: https://github.com/thefactmachine/thin-plate-splines

Comment: The rms package supports multi-dimensional spline models as well as a perimeter function to restrict the 2-d range of estimates. It also is connected to the lattice package and I'm pretty sure you could build a level-plot like this one if you had some data.